# CS5 Bridge labels & rejects in lightroom

Tags: adobe-lightroom, adobe-bridge

I have been working on a huge amount of pictures on my desktop PC from work, using Adobe Bridge to label them.

I now want to process them on my private laptop. Unfortunately, Photoshop CS5 is out of my price range, and I'm currently trying out Lightroom 4. However, when I import the pictures into Lightroom, the keywords and star ratings are visible, but my (color) labels and "rejected" statuses are not visible.

Is it possible to import images into Lightroom while retaining all the metadata from Bridge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To facilitate the interaction between Bride and Lightroom it's possible to use the color labels from bridge by going in the Lightroom menu to

```
Metadata -> Color Label Set
```

And then choose

```
Bridge Default
```

I still lost the rejected status, but with my color labels back up and running, it's just a question of permanently deleting the rejected images before importing them into Lightroom and I'm good to go. Another solution for those that I don't want to delete just yet is to not use the rejected status but one of the color labels.

So the solution was in settings and in a slight adjustment of my work flow.

Comment: Actually the only thing you need to do to make `Lightroom` recognize `Bridge` Color Labels is to match them. Since *they are just text labels assigned to colors in the interface*, you can just set `Bridge` Preferences so that `Red` means "Remove", `Green` means "Good", and so on, and `Lightroom` will recognize them as long you create a Color Label Set with the same set of labels and activate it from the `Metadata` menu. This will also work the other way around, when you view in `Bridge` photos exported from `Lightroom`.